# How can write stored procedure in postgresql and call in php code?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to write a procedure on my table named trail where all the transactions stored related valid login attempts and invalid login attempts. I want to calculate if the same user attempting 5 times with an invalid attempt then it will block for 5 minutes.

I am using this query

```
"select count(*) from trail where username='$username' and date='$todaydate'"
if($count>5)
{
//redirect to blockpage
}
else
{
//check for password and

//redirect to dashboard
}
```

Output:

Trail Table data

```
date    Userid  Blocktime   Validlogin
--------------------------------------
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc 26-08-2019 12:04:08 0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    1
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc 26-08-2019 12:09:08 0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc 26-08-2019 12:13:00 0
```

When I used the above query then its work for only the first five transactions after that it will count older transaction of that user, and update the block time

Table structure

```
date    Userid  Blocktime   Validlogin
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc 26-08-2019 12:04:08 0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    1
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc Null    0
26-08-2019  Abc 26-08-2019 12:04:08 0
```

Actually I want this table structure using a stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you require. Its a function not a procedure but the procedure couldn't return anything so probably not what you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(
                                        p_username VARCHAR(64)
                                    ) RETURNS BOOLEAN
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
        l_attempts integer;
BEGIN

        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO l_attempts
        FROM trail
        WHERE 1=1
        AND user_name = p_username
        AND log_time >= now()::date;


        IF l_attempts > 5 THEN
                RETURN TRUE;
        ELSE
                RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;

END;
$$;
```

In PHP call this function and if it returns true the user should be blocked from logging in.

```
select testfunc('sumituser');
```